# Property-Level Access Control in Parse

Tags: security, parse-platform, acl

The [Data & Security guide at Parse.com](https://www.parse.com/docs/data#security) describes how to control access on class and object level. I am looking for a way to restrict write permissions on certain **properties** of a class for all users. How can this be achieved?

My idea would be to use a One-to-One relationship and restrict the access on the related class. However, this doesn't feel like the canonical way...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to use cloud code. Here is how you could do it :

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("YourObject", function(request, response)
{
    // Find a way to decide if writing is allowed.
    var writingForbidden = (request.master === false);

    if (writingForbidden)
    {
        var readOnlyProperties = ["property1", "property2", "property3", "..."];

        var dirtyProperties = request.object.dirtyKeys();
        for (i = 0 ; i < dirtyProperties.length ; i++) {
            var dirtyProperty = dirtyProperties[i];
            if (readOnlyProperties.indexOf(dirtyProperty) > -1) {
                return response.error("Trying to change a readonly property : " + dirtyProperty);
            }
        }
    }

    return response.success();
}
```